# Asp.net mvc Files required for deployment aren't reference in the project during development

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

After reading quite few articles on deployment, i am bit confused about the procedure.

All the articles refer to dlls which aren't reference in Asp.net mvc project. The dlls are like following :-

- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
- System.Web.Razor.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

I created the [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) application from a tutorial on asp.net website and it works fine in visual studio. In the project, there is no reference to the above given assemblies(not even the razor but i am using razor engine only).

So why should i add the above files to the bin directory if my project is running without referencing them in the first place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those assemblies need to be available somehow.  If you have installed ASP.NET MVC 3 then they will be registered in the GAC (see here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/18/running-an-asp-net-mvc-3-app-on-a-web-server-that-doesn-t-have-asp-net-mvc-3-installed.aspx).

If not (e.g. if you are using shared hosting which doesn't have ASP.NET MVC 3 installed), then you will need to bin deploy them as described here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Refer to the second link to actually do the deployment.  The first link is more for background reading.

Comment: I am talking about the Development. I haven't added them as reference in VS and neither did the VS itself when creating the Asp.net Template. Do you mean to say, VS doesn't need you to add references for these files and they automatically referred under the hood

Comment: Yes that's exactly right.  If they are installed in the Global Assembly Cache then no reference is required.  In brief, it automatically tries to find them in the `bin` directory and then in the `GAC`.  On your dev machine, it always finds them in the `GAC`.  But not on your production server.